# Specifying the Flask reload watch list (extra_files) in code or the `flask run` command

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I have some Flask applications which I run by setting the `FLASK_APP` environment variable and invoking `flask run`. Since `FLASK_DEBUG` is also set, the application conveniently reloads whenever I change some code.

But not all code. There are other files, namely config files that I load with [`app.config.from_pyfile`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Config.from_pyfile), that I want the app to watch too, so it reloads if I change those. How can I do that?

I know I can specify `extra_files` in the built-in Werkzeug server if I invoke it from code. But as I mentioned, I'm actually using the built-in `flask run` command. I have multiple apps in this project, so being able to choose which one to run with `FLASK_APP` has proven convenient... except that there doesn't seem to be a way to specify `extra_files`. I could write some bootstrap code that does both, but I'd prefer to use some built-in way, if it exists.

What would be especially convenient is if I could simply specify the files in the app itself, adding them to a watch list as I load them. Sadly, `extra_files` doesn't seem to be a member of the `App` object, even though it's a parameter in `app.run()`.

I can't imagine this being an uncommon use case. Does Flask provide a way to do what I want?

Comment: Do you want to pass extra_files to flask run?

Comment: @stamaimer: If that's the best solution available, I'll take it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried the following command in `manage.py`:

```
@manager.option('-w', '--wsgi_server', dest='server', default='flask',
            help='[flask|gevent|tornado]')
@manager.option('-p', '--port', dest='port', default=5000,
            help='Port to listen')
@manager.option('-d', '--debug', dest='debug', action="store_true", default=False,
            help='Show debugging information')
def run(server, port, debug):
    app.connexion_app.run(
        port=int(port),
        server=server,
        debug=debug,
        extra_files=[
            './proj/oauth2/swagger.yaml',
            './proj/api/swagger.yaml',
        ])
```

and `extra_files` seems to be picked up fine:

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 336-632-033
 * Detected change in '<-snip->/proj/api/swagger.yaml', reloading
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really in a position to try this out right now, but I will, and upvote if it works. ☺

Comment: 18 more months and I've worked on no Flask projects. Could somebody else share their experiences with this solution here in comments? The solution makes sense, but I'd rather not mark it as an accepted answer, without somebody verifying it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can **export** these variables and specify the file you need.

```
FLASK_APP=/usr/src/app/server.py

# to enable debug to enable reload on file change
FLASK_DEBUG=1

# here specify the file
FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES="/usr/src/app/banuka.txt"
```

I have tried this and it is working as expected. But this doesn't guarantee the browser will reload, being said that you have to do the browser refresh manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES` environment variable.
See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#watch-extra-files-with-the-reloader

Answer (score 0):

require to set debug=True. Not for production environment.