# how to reload the flask server when I change my css code?

Tags: python, css, flask

I am trying to edit my CSS code in the `static` folder.
But the problem is: **Flask is not reloading CSS changes**.

```
<head>
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

I expected the changes but there is no change on editing the css file.

Comment: Is it possible that your CSS is being cached by your browser?

Comment: yes , if i manually reload the server the output is being changed !

Comment: Try Hard Refresh - **Ctrl + F5** or hold Ctrl and click on the Refresh button on your web browser.

Comment: Apart from control = F5, flask offers an option to add extra files to be monitored and cause restart in debug mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688777/specifying-the-flask-reload-watch-list-extra-files-in-code-or-the-flask-run. I have not tested this on css files, but it might be worth a try

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and it was the browser cache not clearing out. I found a solution for Chrome and Firefox: hold down the Shift key while clicking the reload button

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES` environment variable
- `--extra-files` commandline arg
- extra_files array arg to `app.run()`

see [extra files docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#watch-extra-files-with-the-reloader)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that static files are not checked for changes, even when Flask runs in debug mode. Additionally, CSS files are rather more browser related than to the application itself.

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You need to set reload template to true

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
```